# R sorting by most commonly occuring

Tags: r

This is probably very very simple but, I have a vector of phrases, some of which repeat, some of which dont, and I would like a list of unique phrases, sorted by the most commonly occurring.

e.g.

```
vec <- c("hello","hi","hi","greetings","good day", "hi", "hello", "good day","good morning","hello","good day")

sort(unique(vec))

[1] "good day"     "good morning" "greetings"    "hello"        "hi"
```

I would expect "hi" to be first then followed by "hello" then followed by "good day" etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sort(table(vec))` :

```
sort(table(vec), decreasing=TRUE)
# vec
#     good day        hello           hi good morning    greetings 
#            3            3            3            1            1
```